# How to check if a sub string is in quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have this code and I want to check if a sub string is in quotes. I'm trying to make a programming language.

```py
code = """
Console.Print("Hello"); Console.Print("World");
"""
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I found that you can use regex to do this.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: @MattDMo Nothing since I haven't thought about anything yet

Comment: Perhaps you could somehow configure `code.find('(')` and `code.find(')')` to check whatever is inside. However, this only works for the first instances of `(` and `)`.

Comment: So you haven't even done a simple search like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+check+if+a+substring+is+in+quotes+python)? "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: @SanguineL OP is looking for substrings in quotes. Those are parentheses...

Comment: @MattDMo I haven't found anything I could find useful

Comment: @MattDMo He could check for the character after the open parenthesis and before the closing parenthesis with this.

Comment: @SanguineL That's a good idea but the problem is that I can't check the second one as you mentioned if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want to do with the output, but a brute-force approach would be looping through the string.

```js
code = '''Console.Print("Hello"); Console.Print("World");
'''

display = False
words = []
new_word = ''
for letter in code:
    if letter == "\"" and not display:
        display = True
    elif letter == "\"":
        words.append(new_word)
        new_word = ''
        display = False
    if display and letter!='\"':
        new_word +=letter
        
print(words)
```

Probably not the most efficient approach.